# Automate the Salesforce Support Case creation

Tags: api, salesforce-support

In our project, we need to automate the Salesforce Support Case creation. We want to automatically create a case to Salesforce to request changing Trial Org to Permanent org. We want to do it every time a new Trial Org is created.

Is there any API or other automation options available to create a new support case at help.salesforce.com?

Comment: You can use an RPA/UI automation framework like https://robotframework.org/ to simply automate the manual steps to log a case.